# No module named 'urlparse even though I am not using urlparse

Tags: python, ipython, urlparse

I am trying to run the following code on google colab to generate graphs for The Salesman Problem but when I run it I get the error of no module named urlparse found even though I didn't use such module. I tried !pip install urlparse but there is no such module (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urlparse (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urlparse).
I am confused about from where exactly this error appears in order to solve it

```
import time
import argparse
import pprint as pp
import os

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from concorde.tsp import TSPSolver


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--num_samples", type=int, default=10000)
    parser.add_argument("--num_nodes", type=int, default=20)
    parser.add_argument("--node_dim", type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument("--filename", type=str, default=None)
    opts = parser.parse_args()

    if opts.filename is None:
        opts.filename = f"tsp{opts.num_nodes}_concorde.txt"

    # Pretty print the run args
    pp.pprint(vars(opts))

    set_nodes_coord = np.random.random([opts.num_samples, opts.num_nodes, opts.node_dim])
    with open(opts.filename, "w") as f:
        start_time = time.time()
        for nodes_coord in set_nodes_coord:
            solver = TSPSolver.from_data(nodes_coord[:,0], nodes_coord[:,1], norm="GEO")  
            solution = solver.solve()
            f.write( " ".join( str(x)+str(" ")+str(y) for x,y in nodes_coord) )
            f.write( str(" ") + str('output') + str(" ") )
            f.write( str(" ").join( str(node_idx+1) for node_idx in solution.tour) )
            f.write( str(" ") + str(solution.tour[0]+1) + str(" ") )
            f.write( "\n" )
        end_time = time.time() - start_time

    print(f"Completed generation of {opts.num_samples} samples of TSP{opts.num_nodes}.")
    print(f"Total time: {end_time/3600:.1f}h")
    print(f"Average time: {(end_time/3600)/opts.num_samples:.1f}h")
```

Answer (score 2):

urlparse is a builtin python2 library that had its name changed to urllib.parse in python3. It is possible that you're using a library or a version of a library that hasn't yet been upgraded to work with python3.

Your best bet is to run an upgrade on your dependencies. If you still get an error then share the stack trace so we can help you figure out where the source of that error is.

Comment: I upgraded all my dependencies including concorde package but here is what I get as an error :

<ipython-input-10-8afcbb1054d7> in <module>()
      6 import pandas as pd
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from concorde.tsp import TSPSolver

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/concorde/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from operator import itemgetter
      7 from datetime import datetime
----> 8 from urlparse import urljoin
      9 
     10 try:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: Unfortunately the "concorde" library you're trying to use does not work with python3. Your options are to either find a new library or run your code with python2 (which I'm not sure is supposed on google colab).